# How to do searching based on keywords added in page

Tags: plugin-development

I have added keywords and description on my pages. I have to do searching based on those keywords in my website. I am not sure how to do it. And apart from that I also want to show keywords related to that page like a cloud tag

Any help and suggestion is appreciable

Answer (score -1):

There are many `widgets` you can use to do these natively without any programming knowledge. Just simply find the option in the menu and drag the item into a visible sidebar in your theme.

Comment: but about the search bar? I have to search my pages based on those keywords how can it be possible please tell me

Comment: There is also a search widget